# Static code analysis in custom Visual Studio CodeLens Extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions

Starting from [this article](https://www.codingwithcalvin.net/extending-visual-studio-codelens-functionality/) I'm developing a Visual Studio 2022 Extension that add next to standard CodeLens method reference count a custom method reference count invoking an API in our BPM software.
In the context of a CodeLensDataPoint, what is the correct approach to thoroughly analyze the method and obtain information such as the reference class, any interfaces, method visibility indicators, essentially everything one would obtain using reflection.

```
 [Export(typeof(IAsyncCodeLensDataPointProvider))]
 [Name(Id)]
 [ContentType("CSharp")]    
 [LocalizedName(typeof(Resources), Id)]
 [Priority(210)]
 public class CodeLensDataPointProvider : IAsyncCodeLensDataPointProvider
 {
    ...

     public Task<bool> CanCreateDataPointAsync(CodeLensDescriptor descriptor, CodeLensDescriptorContext descriptorContext,
         CancellationToken token)
     {
         if(descriptor.Kind != CodeElementKinds.Method)
             return Task.FromResult(false);

         // here I would like to know method visibility indicator, class, interface implemented by class
                  
         return Task.FromResult(true);
     }

     public Task<IAsyncCodeLensDataPoint> CreateDataPointAsync(CodeLensDescriptor descriptor, CodeLensDescriptorContext descriptorContext,
         CancellationToken token)
     {
         return Task.FromResult<IAsyncCodeLensDataPoint>(new CodeLensDataPoint(descriptor, claActionProvider));
     }
 }
```

Comment: Hi do you mean you want to know is there any build-in function or CodeLens API to get method visibility indicator, class, etc?

Comment: Hi, yes, just like descriptor.Kind